# Creating Groups out of two different lists

Tags: list, linq, linq-group

I guess this is an easy one but I have no clue how to do this.

I have two lists of Persons

```
List<Person> specificPersons
List<Person> allPersons
```

I would like to create groups out of the two complete lists like the following with linq.

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Person>> personsGroups
```

The string will be any custom string. I would use this to display both lists separated by a group header in a Windows 8.1 Metro Application `ListView` using a `CollectionViewSource` binding to the `IEnumerable`.

Comment: What criteria do you want the groups of people to be grouped by?

Comment: Each list should result in a group. Maybe this is the point where I do not really understand how  this works. There is no other criteria to create the group since each list will be a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
string headerSpecific = "Specific";
string headerAll = "All";

var query =
    specificPersons.GroupBy(_ => headerSpecific )
    .Union(
    allPersons.GroupBy(_ => headerAll));
```

Note you have other ways to accomplish similar functionality (although not matching your question's requirements), for instance using anonymous types instead of groups:

```
var query =
    specificPersons.Select(p => new { Header = headerSpecific, p})
    .Union(
    allPersons.Select(p => new { Header = headerAll, p}));
```

Comment: This seems like what I was looking for, I'll test this out in a minute. 
For the second solution with anonymous types - what would the returned type look like?

Comment: An `IEnumerable` for an anonymous type containing a `Header` property of type `string` and a `i` property of type `Person`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a Group property to Person, which you can set via a simple loop on each of your lists.  Then you can do this:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Person>> personsGroups = specificPersons.Concat(allPersons).GroupBy(p => p.Group);
```

Note that this would not make sense if Person is a domain entity and/or exists in your database. Since these groups are for display purposes, use a view model (e.g. PersonViewModel) and add the Group property to that model to avoid changing your domain model.